# Why mysqld isn't locate in /etc/init.d directory in Fedora 16?

Tags: mysql, fedora, mysql-workbench

I was using Fedora 16. Initially I installed MySQL server through RPM package which is downloaded from MySQL website, the version that I installed is 5.5.21-1. I can start the server through /etc/init.d/mysql. When I am trying to install MySQL Workbench from the Fedora's Add/Remove Software utility, I got an error incompatible problem because Fedora's version is 5.5.20.

Thus I uninstall MySQL server and install Fedora's version so that I can install MySQL Workbench. But somehow I notice that the mysqld isn't locate in /etc/init.d anymore? Then when I trying to search through the Internet and found out that I am require to start MySQL using following command:

```
service mysqld start
```

Well, I am able to start MySQL server. When come to the Create New Instance Profile in MySQL Workbench, I couldn't pass the Test Settings section because /etc/init.d/mysqld is missing.

May I know how should I instruct MySQL Workbench not to use /etc/init.d/mysqld, and use `service mysqld start` instead? Or maybe I need to think about why mysqld is no longer inside /etc/init.d anymore?

Comment: Fedora is transitioning to systemd, a completely different way of starting services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping to the latest MySQL version is a good idea. If you just can't install MySQL Workbench from Fedora's repos just get the latest MySQL Workbench rpm from its [download page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) (which is also a *very* good idea). This should work without any issues (assuming that you have installed all of the WB's prerequisites).

The default server profile for Fedora should work OK with the latest MySQL RPM package. If it doesn't you just have to figure out the commands to start/stop the server and query for its status.

Just make sure to uninstall the MySQL Server version that comes in Fedora's repos before installing the latest MySQL version to avoid each package interfering with the other.

Don't hesitate to ask further questions if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rpm -qf /usr/bin/mysql` to get the name of your mysql-RPM package name and than execute `rpm -ql <name>` to list all installed files from that package. RPM should come with prepared mysqld so it should be in the listed files: `rpm -ql <name> | grep mysqld`.

Comment: or just one step: `rpm -qlf /usr/bin/mysql`. BTW, I normally use `-lv` instead of `-l`.

Comment: thanx for the update. I'm normally on deb packages via apt :)